# PHP strtotime() is not returning the correct month

Tags: php

Being that the current month/year is January 2012, why does the following code return December 2011 and not November 2011?

```
echo date("F Y", strtotime("-2 months"));
```

This is on PHP 5.3.0 if it makes a difference.

Comment: Perhaps because it is Jan. 31. Going 2 months back might be something like Dec. 1

Comment: What time zone is the server in? In some places it is February right now.

Comment: Just tested in PST, and got Dec 1

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To get what you are looking for you can use this rather verbose version instead:

```
echo date("F Y", strtotime("first day of this month - 2 months"));
```

The problem with your original version is described in detail here: http://derickrethans.nl/obtaining-the-next-month-in-php.html. Quoted below:

> Over and over again PHP users complain that next month in PHP's
>   date-string parser doesn't go to the next month, but instead skips to
>   the one after next month; like in the following example:
>
> ```
> <?php
> $d = new DateTime( '2010-01-31' );
> $d->modify( 'next month' );
> echo $d->format( 'F' ), "\n";
> ?>
> ```
>
> The output of the little script will be March. March obviously doesn't
>   follow January as February is in between. However, the current
>   behavior is correct. The following happens internally:
>
> next month increases the month number (originally 1) by one. This
>   makes the date 2010-02-31. The second month (February) only has 28
>   days in 2010, so PHP auto-corrects this by just continuing to count
>   days from February 1st. You then end up at March 3rd. The formatting
>   strips off the year and day, resulting in the output March. This can
>   easily be seen when echoing the date with a full date format, which
>   will output March 3rd, 2010:

This is for adding months, but the same applies in reverse when subtracting months; there was no November 31st, so the strtotime method "corrects" it into December 1st.

Comment: Thanks for that link. I would definitely argue that this is not expected behavior and can sneak up on someone in months with a 31st day.

Comment: Yes, I would also argue this is in clear violation of the Principle of Least Surprise. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_surprise